# Delete a tagged section of text plus the next line in a file using sed

Tags: sed

If I have a file like this with variable length sections of text between tags.

```
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag2>
-- </tag2>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

I'm trying to use sed to delete the tag2 section plus the line after it, so I end up with this:

```
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

I know I can use the following to get rid of everything in the tag2 section, not including the line after the section, but I can't figure out how to expand it to also delete the next line.

`sed -e '/<tag2>/,/<\/tag2>/d' file`

I thought it would be something simple like this, but that doesn't work for a tagged section with no content like tag2.  It will work for tag1 or tag3.

`sed -e '/<tag2>/,/<\/tag2>/{N;d}' file`

Comment: Does every line of your file REALLY start with ```-- ```? If not then please [edit] the example in your question to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<tag2>/{:a;n;/<\/tag2>/!ba;n;d};p' file
```

Match `<tag2>` and continue fetching lines until one with `</tag2>` is matched, then fetch and delete the next line.

Print all other lines.

N.B. The option `-n` turns off implicit printing.

Alternative:

```
sed '/<tag2>/{:a;N;/<\/tag2>/!ba;N;d}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your files don't REALLY have `--`  at the start of every line then all you need is this using GNU sed for -E and -z:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/<tag2>.*<\/tag2>\n\n//' file

<tag1>
some text
</tag1>

<tag3>
other stuff
</tag3>
```

or GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='<tag2>.*</tag2>\n\n' -v ORS= '1' file

<tag1>
some text
</tag1>

<tag3>
other stuff
</tag3>
```

If there really are `--` s or other text at the start of each line then:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/[^\n]*<tag2>.*<\/tag2>\n[^\n]*\n//' file1
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

```
$ awk -v RS='[^\n]*<tag2>.*</tag2>\n[^\n]*\n' -v ORS= '1' file1
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

The sed scripts read all of your file into memory at once while the awk scripts read the part before  and the part after  separately.

Alternatively, using any awk, for either input format and only reading 1 line at a time into memory:

```
$ awk '/<tag2>/{f=1} f{n=NR+2} /<\/tag2>/{f=0} n<=NR' file

<tag1>
some text
</tag1>

<tag3>
other stuff
</tag3>
```

```
$ awk '/<tag2>/{f=1} f{n=NR+2} /<\/tag2>/{f=0} n<=NR' file1
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

```
$ awk '/<tag2>/,/<\/tag2>/{f=1; last=NR} f && NR>last+1{f=0} !f' file
--
-- <tag1>
-- some text
-- </tag1>
--
-- <tag3>
-- other stuff
-- </tag3>
--
```

Comment: question: "using sed"

Comment: @starball we frequently see questions talking about a specific UNIX tool because that's what the OP thinks they need, then we post a solution using a different UNIX tool and it gets accepted. Seeing one tool tagged doesn't mean the answer must only be using that tool, it typically just means that's the tool the OP's code sample is using.